# Django Sessions Login

Tags: django, django-sessions

in the following code section of my Django project, I have a function login_view. This function is supposed to log in a user.
My question would be how I can use Django's sessions to start a separate session at each login:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "users/login.html", {
                "message": "Invalid credentials"
            })   
    return render(request, "users/login.html")
```

This is what i tried:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            request.session['username'] = username
            request.session['password'] = password
            request.session['user'] = user
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "users/login.html", {
                "message": "Invalid credentials"
            })   
    return render(request, "users/login.html")
```

Comment: django.contrib.auth.login function manages sessions automatically. You don't need to tackle with session to store user information

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do, that `login(request, user)` is enough to set up / create a new session. Also you should absolutely not store the users credentials in the session. Many of the supported session engines store this data on your side, which means you end up having the users credentials in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

**Tyr this method :**

```
 def login(request):
        if "username" in request.session:
            return redirect("home")
        if request.method=="POST":
            username=request.POST.get('username')
            password=request.POST.get('password')
    
            user=user_details.objects.filter(username=username,password=password)
            if user.exists():
                messages.success(request, 'Successfully Logged In')
                request.session["username"]=username
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                context["error"] = "Invalid username or password"
    
    
        return render(request,'login.html',context=context)
```